# Finding $x,y$ with $x<y\leq2x$ using the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm unsure how to apply the pigeonhole principle to this problem.

> Prove that for any choice of $7$ distinct numbers from the set of 
>       integers from $1$ to $126$ inclusive, there will always be 
>       two numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x<y≤2x$.

In this context, I'm unsure what would be regarded as the "pigeons" and the "pigeonholes" or how to incorporate them.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Basically if you pick any two numbers from the set {$x,x+1,...2x$}, the property will always be satisfied. Try to divide $\{1,2,..126\}$ into 6 such sets.

Comment: did you observe that $2^7=128$ has a close relation with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the pigeonholes to be the following 6 sets. 
$$\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6\}, \{7, 8, .. 14\}, \{15, 16, .. 30\}, \{31, 32,.. 62\}, \{63, 64.. 126\}$$

The sets collectively form the natural numbers from  1 to 126 inclusive. There are $6$ holes and   $7$ pigeons implying at least two natural numbers must be chosen from the same set.

Each set is of the form $\{p, p +1, p+2,.. 2p\}$. Let $x, y$ be the two elements chosen from the same set. Without loss of generality we may assume $x \lt y$ but $y \le 2p$ and $p \le x$, $\implies y \le 2x $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  The choice of $126$ suggests the conclusion is not true for $127$.  See if you can construct a counterexample for $127$.  (Further hint:  If there is a counterexample, one of the $7$ numbers must be $127$.  Why?)